# Why does MATLAB crash with "MATLAB has encountered an internal error and needs to close"?

Tags: matlab, caffe

"Matlab has encountered an internal problem and needs to close"

```
MATLAB crash file:C:\Users\MJ\AppData\Local\Temp\matlab_crash_dump.7584-1:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
              abort() detected at Thu Jan  4 15:30:18 2018
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Default Encoding    : KSC_5601
  Deployed            : false
  Graphics card 1     : NVIDIA ( 0x10de ) NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 Version 23.21.13.8871 (2017-12-15)
  Host Name           : DESKTOP-EGKG0V7
  MATLAB Architecture : win64
  MATLAB Entitlement ID: 2385114
  MATLAB Root         : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b
  MATLAB Version      : 9.3.0.713579 (R2017b)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Microsoft Windows 10 Education
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.8.0_121-b13 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : Version 10.0 (Build 16299)

Fault Count: 1

Stack Trace (captured):
[  0] 0x0000000012795e83                              bin\win64\libmwfl.dll+00155267 foundation::core::diag::thread_context::unspecified_bool+00000051

[  1] 0x0000000012794478                              bin\win64\libmwfl.dll+00148600 foundation::core::diag::stacktrace_base::capture+00000024

[  2] 0x00000000127979ce                              bin\win64\libmwfl.dll+00162254 foundation::core::diag::symbols::getSymbolAddress+00006494

[  3] 0x000000001279a807                              bin\win64\libmwfl.dll+00174087 foundation::core::diag::disable_terminate_dialog+00000887

[  4] 0x00000000174df615                                  bin\win64\mcr.dll+00652821 mnShutdownMCR+00023605

[  5] 0x00000000174df2a1                                  bin\win64\mcr.dll+00651937 mnShutdownMCR+00022721

[  6] 0x00000000174df378                                  bin\win64\mcr.dll+00652152 mnShutdownMCR+00022936

[  7] 0x00000000174dc5e9                                  bin\win64\mcr.dll+00640489 mnShutdownMCR+00011273

[  8] 0x00000000174ddc59                                  bin\win64\mcr.dll+00646233 mnShutdownMCR+00017017

[  9] 0x00007ffa0fd4a9ff                   C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll+00436735 raise+00000463

[ 10] 0x00007ffa0fd4b6f1                   C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll+00440049 abort+00000049

[ 11] 0x00007ffa003b469a D:\T_caffe\caffe\caffe-windows\matlab\+caffe\private\glog.dll+00018074 google::Demangle+00008410

[ 12] 0x00007ffa003b9de2 D:\T_caffe\caffe\caffe-windows\matlab\+caffe\private\glog.dll+00040418 google::LogMessage::SendToLog+00000738

[ 13] 0x00007ffa003b7a25 D:\T_caffe\caffe\caffe-windows\matlab\+caffe\private\glog.dll+00031269 google::LogMessage::Flush+00000213

[ 14] 0x00007ffa003b61e2 D:\T_caffe\caffe\caffe-windows\matlab\+caffe\private\glog.dll+00025058 google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal+00000018

[ 15] 0x00007ff9c9f5db3a D:\T_caffe\caffe\caffe-windows\matlab\+caffe\private\caffe_.mexw64+00842554 mexFunction+00770010

[ 16] 0x00007ff9c9ea1dba D:\T_caffe\caffe\caffe-windows\matlab\+caffe\private\caffe_.mexw64+00073146 mexFunction+00000602

[ 17] 0x00000000fc60234a                               bin\win64\libmex.dll+00140106 mexRunMexFile+00000314

[ 18] 0x00000000fc600d22                               bin\win64\libmex.dll+00134434 mexFeature_mexver+00002146

[ 19] 0x00000000fc5ffab7                               bin\win64\libmex.dll+00129719 mexUnlock+00028455

[ 20] 0x00000000175aca93                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00117395 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh_impl+00000835

[ 21] 0x00000000175ac73e                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00116542 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000062

[ 22] 0x000000001759a8d8                     bin\win64\pgo\m_dispatcher.dll+00043224 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00001032

[ 23] 0x000000001849794e                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00227662

[ 24] 0x0000000018494571                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00214385

[ 25] 0x000000001849b3a6                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00242598

[ 26] 0x000000001849bfb3                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00245683

[ 27] 0x000000001849dff5                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00253941

[ 28] 0x000000001849d44f                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00250959

[ 29] 0x000000001849d822                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00251938

[ 30] 0x000000001856331b                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+01061659 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::MatlabIrTree> >::get_instance+00604503

[ 31] 0x000000001856ad46                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+01092934 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::MatlabIrTree> >::get_instance+00635778

[ 32] 0x000000001856a570                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+01090928 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::MatlabIrTree> >::get_instance+00633772

[ 33] 0x00000000184fa4d6                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00632022 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::MatlabIrTree> >::get_instance+00174866

[ 34] 0x00000000184f9ccd                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00629965 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::MatlabIrTree> >::get_instance+00172809

[ 35] 0x00000000184f9be6                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00629734 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::MatlabIrTree> >::get_instance+00172578

[ 36] 0x00000000184f35a5                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00603557 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::MatlabIrTree> >::get_instance+00146401

[ 37] 0x00000000184f3532                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00603442 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::MatlabIrTree> >::get_instance+00146286

[ 38] 0x00000000184f71d5                            bin\win64\pgo\m_lxe.dll+00618965 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_oarchive,MathWorks::lxe::MatlabIrTree> >::get_instance+00161809

[ 39] 0x00000000177b5b63                    bin\win64\pgo\m_interpreter.dll+00416611 inEvalCmdWithLocalReturn+00000063

[ 40] 0x00000000fb60de26                          bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00122406 mnParser+00001254

[ 41] 0x000000001747bdb1                                  bin\win64\mcr.dll+00245169 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadSingletonToCurrent+00029793

[ 42] 0x000000001747ace5                                  
bin\win64\mcr.dll+00240869 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadSingletonToCurrent+00025493

[ 43] 0x000000001747ad53                                  bin\win64\mcr.dll+00240979 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadSingletonToCurrent+00025603

[ 44] 0x000000001747b6e1                                  bin\win64\mcr.dll+00243425 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadSingletonToCurrent+00028049

[ 45] 0x00000000fd02cc77                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00642167 iqm::UserEvalPlugin::pre+00028951

[ 46] 0x00000000fd039cfc                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00695548 iqm::UserEvalPlugin::pre+00082332

[ 47] 0x00000000fd02737f                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00619391 iqm::UserEvalPlugin::pre+00006175

[ 48] 0x00000000fd02cc16                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00642070 iqm::UserEvalPlugin::pre+00028854

[ 49] 0x00000000fd027863                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00620643 iqm::UserEvalPlugin::pre+00007427

[ 50] 0x00000000fd03c8b6                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00706742 iqm::UserEvalPlugin::pre+00093526

[ 51] 0x00000000fd0080f7                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00491767 iqm::PackagedTaskPlugin::PackagedTaskPlugin+00000759

[ 52] 0x00000000fd0088bf                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00493759 iqm::PackagedTaskPlugin::execute+00000879

[ 53] 0x00000000fd00817d                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00491901 iqm::PackagedTaskPlugin::PackagedTaskPlugin+00000893

[ 54] 0x00000000fd008708                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00493320 iqm::PackagedTaskPlugin::execute+00000440

[ 55] 0x00000000fcfdbd3a                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00310586 iqm::Iqm::setupIqmFcnPtrs+00079802

[ 56] 0x00000000fcfdbc06                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00310278 iqm::Iqm::setupIqmFcnPtrs+00079494

[ 57] 0x00000000fcfbf5be                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00193982 iqm::Iqm::deliver+00004046

[ 58] 0x00000000fcfc0545                                  bin\win64\iqm.dll+00197957 iqm::Iqm::deliver+00008021

[ 59] 0x00000001001237c1                        bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01259457 
services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::dispatchOne+00021505

[ 60] 0x0000000100128663                        
bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01279587 sysq::addProcessPendingEventsUnitTestHook+00002211

[ 61] 0x0000000100128850                        bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01280080 sysq::addProcessPendingEventsUnitTestHook+00002704

[ 62] 0x0000000100129c26                        bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01285158 sysq::getCondition+00003462

[ 63] 0x000000010012ac66                        bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01289318 svWS_ProcessPendingEvents+00000230

[ 64] 0x000000001747c244                                  bin\win64\mcr.dll+00246340 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadSingletonToCurrent+00030964

[ 65] 0x000000001747c964                                  bin\win64\mcr.dll+00248164 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadSingletonToCurrent+00032788

[ 66] 0x0000000017472762                                  bin\win64\mcr.dll+00206690 mcr_process_events+00008818

[ 67] 0x00000000172e23c5                             bin\win64\MVMLocal.dll+00271301 mvm_server::inproc::LocalFactory::terminate+00088005

[ 68] 0x00000000fa957669                                  bin\win64\mvm.dll+01209961 mvm::detail::initLocalMvmHack+00000569

[ 69] 0x00000000fa957e2b                                  bin\win64\mvm.dll+01211947 mvm::detail::SessionImpl::privateSession+00000555

[ 70] 0x00000000fa958051                                  bin\win64\mvm.dll+01212497 mvm::detail::SessionImpl::privateSession+00001105

[ 71] 0x0000000140007833                               bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00030771

[ 72] 0x000000014000863f                               bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00034367

[ 73] 0x00007ffa10ad1fe4                   C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+00073700 BaseThreadInitThunk+00000020

[ 74] 0x00007ffa1348ef91                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00454545 RtlUserThreadStart+00000033
```

This error was detected while a MEX-file was running. If the MEX-file
is not an official MathWorks function, please examine its source code
for errors. Please consult the External Interfaces Guide for information
on debugging MEX-files.

Comment: What code are you trying to run?

Comment: It is an error message indicating that there is  problem within MATLAB.  You can solve this by MathWorks Support Team. Please look at (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/261366-why-does-matlab-crash-with-matlab-has-encountered-an-internal-error-and-needs-to-close).

Comment: This doesn't look like an internal MATLAB error. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

### MATLAB crashes due to an unhandled exception in a mex file or compiled code called by a mex file

The error message tells you where the error happened:

> This error was detected while a MEX-file was running.

That is, this is not a MATLAB error but a uncaught exception in a mex function (or code called by that mex function, which is usually the case). This is why MATLAB crashes rather than just outputs an error, as it would do for any caught exception. The error trace can help you find the culprit. Look for `mexFunction` in the stack trace and you will find which mex file is to blame:

> [ 16] 0x00007ff9c9ea1dba D:\T_caffe\caffe\caffe-windows\matlab+caffe\private\caffe_.mexw64+00073146 mexFunction+00000602

So the error originates in Caffe's MATLAB interface. Look *above* this line to find where the exception actually happened. At this point you might be stumped as large traces of unknown libraries are usually impossible to decipher. Your options are now the options of anyone trying to debug a crash. My recommendation:

1. Find the call to Caffe in MATLAB that is causing the crash. Save your workspace right before the call so you can easily restore it when MATLAB crashes.
2. See that the crash is reproduced.
3. Look closely at your inputs and see if you can find something fishy.
4. If not, find some basic example for running the same function, then gradually work your way from that to your own inputs and see when crashes start happening.

This should help you narrow down what is causing the crash. A different option is to get the source code, build it with debug symbols and debug it by attaching to MATLAB. Depending on your setup, this could be overkill or else lead you into code you don't understand.

You might, on an off-chance, find an actual bug in the software you are using. I don't know how stable Caffe and its MATLAB interface are. However it is best to assume that widely used libraries are more stable than your own code and start your debugging process from there. Good luck!